# HTTP POST request failing specifically on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I am developing an iOS/Android app with React Native and I am getting an error on Android.

I am using the expo-image-picker library https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

This is the code which works perfectly on iOS:

```js
    const prepareResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      quality: 0.5,
      capture: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      allowsEditing: true,
      allowsMultipleSelection: false,
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    });

    const androidResult = await ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync();
    const result = androidResult?.length ? androidResult[0] : prepareResult;

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      const localUri = result.uri;
      const filename = localUri.split("/").pop();
      const match = filename ? /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename) : "";
      const type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", { uri: localUri, name: filename, type });

      fetch(`${API}/uploadAvatar`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: bearer,
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: formData,
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          setImage(json.file);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log({ err });
          Alert.alert("There was an error uploading your profile picture.");
        });
    }
```

On Android after I crop the image, it goes straight to the `.catch` method without even going through any of the `.then` methods.

I checked this https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickergetpendingresultasync which contains a note:

> Note: Make sure that you handle MainActivity destruction on Android. See ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync.

Any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not an `expo` project, but a `react-native` project,

It is recommended to use a [react-native-image-cropicker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker).

- example

```js
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

//select image
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image);
});

//select from Camera
ImagePicker.openCamera({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true,
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image);
});
```

Comment: It is an expo project.